# Flutter Firestore how to check customer is exist or not by mobile number

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check user is exist or not in **Firestore**. Below are my code

```
Future<bool> _checkCustomerExist() async {
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('customer')
        .where('mobile', isEqualTo: _customerFormData.mobile)
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    if (documents.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I'm checking it by compression of `mobile` field. All are working good but problem is when I go to edit customer same method call before edit. So each time I have to forcefully edit mobile number too. Question is how can put condition here like 'documentID' is notEqual to current customer 'documentID' ?

Comment: Could you try to rephrase the question for me, please?

Comment: Why are calling this Method in case of edit customer - you already have the customer created. Plus if you have same form for adding & editing customer - why not use two different methods differentiate by bool value `edit : true` for editing mode in form & `edit: false` for new user creation. this way you avoid calling same method.

Comment: @anmol.majhail - Yes i'm using same page (Create/Edit) and I have done editing and creation mode by using flag.. But how can we do For Ex. If user "A" added by mobile 111, same "B" added with mobile 222. If I go to edit user "A" and change name "A" to "C" that giving me error like mobile number already exist. Here If I remove to check duplicate user entry then We can also here change user "A" to "C " with mobile 222 also.

Comment: If the Operation is for changing name `"A" to "C"` then the operation on database document is of update - so no need check for mobile number.In my view In Edit mode editing mobile number should not be allowed as each user unique point is mobile.